# Obtain pop-id or IP address when client logs into Dovecot server

Tags: authentication, dovecot

**Background**
I have been doing some research on the Dovecot mail server documentation on ways to get client information when a client connects to the server. I am interested in using these to program an application on the server side, but have currently found no methods to get this information.

**Question**

Is there a way to get detailed information about a client who connects to a Dovecot server upon authentication?

Comment: I think I might be able to use Dovecot's `rawlog` functionality to achieve this, but I'm going to do some more research to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using Dovecot's specification for Post-Login scripting.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PostLoginScripting

After once a shell script is run, environmental variables can be used to obtain the user name and IP address. This information is detailed in the link above.